# this error appears when textbox is null: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

when the cursor focus first time there's no problem, then i type a numbers in the textbox.. but when i deleted all of the numbers and the textbox clear, this error appears.

Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

this is my code

```
Private Sub txtjmluang_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtjmluang.TextChanged

        lblsisauang.Text = Val(txttotal.Text - txtjmluang.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: dont use `Val` ever.  Use `option Strict` always (`txttotal.Text - txtjmluang.Text`) is simply illegal.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your TextBox has valid data in before you try and use it as part of you calculation, i.e.:

```
Private Sub txtjmluang_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtjmluang.TextChanged
        Dim val1, val2 as double
        if Double.TryParse(txttotal.Text, val1) and Double.TryParse(txtjmluang.Text, val2) Then
              lblsisauang.Text = (val1 - val2).ToString()
        end if
End Sub
```

If `txttotal.Text` or `txtjmluang.Text` do not have valid numbers in then it will not try to add them together.

Comment: **why** parse the value of the textboxes containting strings, then still use `txttotal.Text - txtjmluang.Text`??? Bad answer

Comment: Edited to use the parsed values for the calculations. Although the previous text calculations would have worked as .Net would have implicitly converted the values to Double (as it was previously).

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` to test that assertion.

Comment: Option Strict would obviously cause calculations on string to be invalid. But as I was trying to answer the questions original error Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid. I decided to focus my answer on solving that.

Comment: why still using an VB6 function in your answer when you've provided a solution for that in other part of the same code?, its a confusing solution, unnecessary to re-validate a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:
(I'm ignoring the comments by others, if this is how you'd like to make your calculations, I'll attempt to resolve your issue using your logic)

```
Private Sub txtjmluang_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtjmluang.TextChanged
    Try
        If txttotal.Text.Length <> 0 AND txtjmluang.Text <> 0 Then

            lblsisauang.Text = Val(txttotal.Text - txtjmluang.Text)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    'Catch error if one is still thrown after above code; Not pretty, exceptions are costly performance wise.

    End Try
End Sub
```